# boost statechart: Is it still maintained?

Tags: boost, boost-statechart, boost-msm

I currently use boost::state_chart in one of my projects. As the changelog [1] Shows the last activity in boost 1.46.0, is it still maintained or should i switch to boost::MSM?

[1]http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/statechart/doc/future_and_history.html#ChangeHistory